# Selenium with python on MacOS always giving OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My system:
- MacOS Sierra (10.12.6)
- Python 3.5.2
- selenium 3.8.1

I am trying to use selenium with python so I can automatically scroll the browser page (google image search results, to scrape the images).

I have done `brew install chromedriver` and also downloaded the binaries from the official chrome repo https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads (version 2.35) and placed it in a path (`/Users/me/bin/chromedriver`) which I added to my system PATH.

Whenever I try to run

`from selenium import webdriver
  test = webdriver.Chrome()`

or even `test = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/me/bin/chromedriver')`

I just get the error: `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`

I did extensive research on this but all the solutions just reiterate what I've already done.

Here is the whole error message:

---

```
In [15]: test = webdriver.Chrome()

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e726c5f1fb80> in <module>()
----> 1 test = webdriver.Chrome()

~/anaconda/envs/rllab3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options)
     66             service_args=service_args,
     67             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 68         self.service.start()
     69
     70         try:

~/anaconda/envs/rllab3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     74                                             stdout=self.log_file,
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:
     78             raise

~/anaconda/envs/rllab3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
    945                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    946                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 947                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    948         except:
    949             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~/anaconda/envs/rllab3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1549                             else:
   1550                                 err_msg += ': ' + repr(orig_executable)
-> 1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
   1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553

OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

---

Comment: It mostly is because of a wrong version of the chromedriver. Are you sure you downloaded the correct binary for your OS?

Comment: yeah, I mean it's straightforward mac, win or linux.